# Ionic StatusBar undefined. Default is coming light

Tags: ionic-framework, default, statusbar

I am trying to get the default StatusBar which is black, but it's coming light. When I try to set as black the error is Uncaught ReferenceError: StatusBar is not defined including the plugin on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git.
I removed and added several times, but the StatusBar is still light.

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-media 2.1.0 "Media"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.0 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
```

The code is:

```
console.log(StatusBar);
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the `deviceready` event to be able to use Cordova plugins.

The simplest way to do this would be to wrap your code in a `ionic.Platform.ready()` call, like this:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same problem.

1. just delete the platform,
2. and delete all plugins.
3. clean your project
4. then add your plugins again,
5. then add the platform again.
6. compile and run.

ensure also that you delete manually the plugins folder from your projects after deleting you plugins using `cordova plugin rm <PLUGIN NAME>`.

Tell me if it worked with you. Happy Coding.

Comment: Yeah!! It worked.. The error on browser remains, but on emulator it's as I want. Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome bro, according to stackover flow terms, if this answer solved your question, please vote up and marked as answer by tick the correct behind the asnwer. Glad to help you anytime.